# Basic Complex Analysis Question: simplification of $e^{2\pi i\left(17-\frac{1}{3}\right)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have  the following detail of a derivation:
$$
\begin{align}
[\dots] &= 2^{50}\cdot e^{2\pi i\left(17-\frac{1}{3}\right)} \\
&= 2^{50}\cdot e^{-\frac{2\pi}{3} i}
\end{align}
$$

[See source (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEkcZ.png)

What happened to 17 in this question?

Answer (score 2):

$$
e^{2i\pi\left(17-\frac{1}{3}\right)} = e^{2i\pi\cdot 17}\cdot e^{2i\pi\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)} 
$$
and
$$
e^{2i\pi k} = 1
$$for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.